# Sampling fixed number of instances from population in R

Tags: r

I have a variable that contains some numbers which change throughout the program.

e.g.:

```
a<-c(1,2,4,6,5)
```

I would like to take a fixed number of samples (3) every time:

```
sample(a,3,replace=FALSE)
```

In some cases it could be that a < 3 in such cases I get the following error:

> Error in sample(a, 3, replace = FALSE, prob = c(weights)) :
> cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

Is there a way to sample such that if a<3 than it takes as much as it can?
For example, if a=2 and sample size should be 3 then it only takes 2

Comment: sure; `sample(a,min(3,length(a)),replace=FALSE)`, or write a small function `mysample <- function(x,n) { sample(x, min(n, length(x)), replace=FALSE)}`.  `mysample(a,3)` gives `[1] 4 5 6`; `mysample(a,7)` gives `[1] 5 4 6 2 1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sample(a, min(length(a), 3), replace=FALSE)
```

Comment: `min()` returns the smaller of its arguments.  In this instance, the result is to call `sample()` with a 2nd parameter value of 3 whenener the a vector has 3 items or more, and otherwise whatever the number of items is  (`length(a)`).

Answer (score 1):

You could add a control `if` statement before you sample to check the length of your `a` and adjust `my.size` accordingly.

```
> my.size <- 3
> a <- 1:3
> if (length(a) <= 3)  { 
>     my.size <- length(a)
>     message(paste("Sampling size was reduced to ", my.size, ".", sep = ""))
> }
Sampling size was reduced to 2.
> my.size
[1] 2
> sample(a, size = my.size, replace=FALSE)
[1] 1 2
```

Comment: +1 for the message.  Otherwise, the `min()` setup is of course cleaner ;)